# Consulta sql en python pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

Deseo hacer una consulta sql con python pandas, y la consulta lleva parámetros. Este código en el que saco uno de los parámetros (Ticker) funciona,

```
rbefore=pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from patmesrt WHERE Ticker='6A' AND Mes=%s AND Date < %s", conn, index_col='Date',params={patterns.index[i],str(patterns.Mes[i]),fecha})
```

Y sin embargo, cuando lo pongo como parámetro me da error. Es el Ticker='6A':

```
rbefore=pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from patmesrt WHERE Ticker=%s AND Mes=%s AND Date < %s", conn, index_col='Date',params={patterns.index[i],str(patterns.Mes[i]),fecha})
```

El dataframe patterns tiene esta estructura, en la que Ticker es el índice:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porqué ocurre esto. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme lo agradecería.
Un saludo

Comment: Creo que te faltan comillas alrededor del valor del ticker, es decir: `"... WHERE Ticker='%s' AND ..."`

Comment: No es eso. Al poner las comillas me sale error SQL. Gracias por la aportación

Comment: Algo no me cuadra en los ejemplos que das. En el primero en `params` pasas tres cosas, cuando la cadena solo tiene dos `%s`. Aparte de eso, las variables que pasas en `params` en ambos ejemplos las has encerrado entre llaves, lo que convierte el parámetro en un `set()` cuyo orden interno no es predecibe. Usa paréntesis para que sea una tupla, que esas sí mantienen el orden.

Comment: Perfecto. Muchísimas gracias. Era lo del paréntesis en vez de las llaves. Estaba cogiendo mal los parámetros. Gracias. Solucionado